# Coloring symmetry problem

Tags: combinatorics

Problem: **Given 5 colors to choose from, how many ways can we color the four unit squares of a $2\times 2$ board, given that two colorings are considered the same if one is a rotation of the other?**

I saw an existing thread on this question but the answers used Burnside's Lemma, but I am not familiar with Group Theory (and I don't think it is necessary for this problem).

I know how to do this problem if each square on the board must be a different color: There are $5*4*3*2$ possible colorings for the four unit squares and we just divide that amount by 4 to account for rotationally similar arrangements.

However, this problem implies that all squares can be the same color, so I am unsure how to do it.

Comment: "*and we just divide that amount by $4$ to account for rotationally similar arrangements*"  Yes... that is what burnsides lemma tells you to do.  You have been using burnsides lemma all along, though a perhaps simplified form for a special case.

Comment: So, you've counted how many ways to do this if they were all different colors.  Now... how about if there were three colors present (*one was repeated twice*).  Count if the squares of the same color are adjacent (*using the square on the left as a reference point*), count if they are apart (*no good reference point*).  Now, if only two colors appear, what if both colors appear twice?  Together versus apart.  If one color appears three times and the other once (*use the color appearing once as a reference point*).  If all four squares are the same color.

Comment: if you have, for example, the coloration $\begin{tabular}{ccc} A & B\\B & A \end{tabular}$, two rotations are the same.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I solved it.